# Compare two arrays values, and populate if no match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need help with matching two arrays. I have TypeScript in the example code, but it can be understood since its about array operations more or less.

**In short:**

I have two arrays; `myItems[]` and `allItems[]`. `myItems[]` can only hold maximum 4 values.

I want to first check if the items in `myItems[]` is 4, AND/OR exist in the other array `allItems[]`.

If NOT: populate `myItems[]` with values from `allItems[]` (until it contains 4 values) and/or replace the items that is missing (relative to allItems[]) with other items in `allItems[]` (I'm trying to use default values instead of randomly taking values in my example code).

**Description:**

I have a widgets (quick links) module that show 4 links at a time, but there are in total 20 different links (or more). All links is stored in a list and each has its own unique ID. In code, all links is extracted and returned in an array (like the allItems[] in above example).

The user can save the links he/she wants to show in the widget. The user settings is stored and returned as an array with the ID of the links that the user have saved. Like the `myItems[]` above,

**Problem:**

I have a solution that check the length of the `myItems[]`, and if needed populates items from the `allItems[]` one. However, it does NOT check if the items in the user array exist in `allItems[]` and then populates it with the default links. In practical it means that the user can save links and it will be shown in the widget as intended. BUT if a link is removed in the list (which will then be removed in the `allItems` array) only 3 items will be shown as the `myItems[]` doesn't check with the `allItems[]` array to see if it exists there.

**Code:**

```
    public async getUserWidgets(): Promise<Widget[]> {

    let allWidgets = await this.getAllWidgets(); //Array with all the links ID from the list

    let userRepository = new UserProfileRepository(this.absoluteWebUrl);

     let userSettings = await

    userRepository.getUserExtensionValues(this.context); //Extracting the user Settings which contains the ID of the saved linksvar

    result:Widget[] = []; //the array where the result will go in



    //if the user doesnt have any saved links, or if the user have less than 4 saved links



    if (userSettings == null || userSettings.QuickLinksWidgets == null || 
 userSettings.QuickLinksWidgets.length < 4)

    {result = allWidgets.filter((w) => {return w.defaultWidget;}).slice(0,4);



    }

    else {var ids =userSettings.QuickLinksWidgets;



    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    let id = '' + ids[i];let w = allWidgets.filter((e) => { return e.id == id;});

    if (w.length == 0) {

    continue;}



    result.push(w[0]);}}

    return new Promise<Widget[]>(async (resolve) => {resolve(result);});}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to check if an array holds a value is using the `includes()` method.

```
for(let value of myitems){
    if(allitems.includes(value)){
        console.log("Duplicate")
    }
}
```

The above code will loop through each value in your `myitems` array and test if that value is in the `allitems` array.